# Powershell - How to filter array object with multiple keys/fields/columns of another array object EFFICIENTLY?

Tags: arrays, powershell, parsing, filter, compare

I am trying to get items in an array object(has all the data and way more rows) (array object 1) which also exists in a different array (Array object 2)(has some of the fields, and fewer rows)

How would I get the data from array object 1 using multiple fields since many fields repeat?

Important point: No single Entry in a field is unique, but combinations of 4 fields are

Specifically how to do this in a few steps/lines of code and without much time and/or resource consumption (I can figure out how to do this using loops but that's inefficient)

Example

**ARRAY OBJECT 1**

```
Number : 10
Place  : UT
Color  : yellow
Zone   : FAHIVT
Group  : 20


Number : 29
Place  : NY
Color  : white
Zone   : HWOUKK
Group  : 8


Number : 66
Place  : TX
Color  : black
Zone   : KZZGKI
Group  : 2


number : 127
Place  : AL
Color  : white
Zone   : DMXDZR
Group  : 14
```

**ARRAY OBJECT 2**

```
Place : NY
Color : white
Group : 2
Zone  : TVQJPN

Place : PA
Color : blue
Group : 4
Zone  : AAYYSN

Place : NJ
Color : red
Group : 17
Zone  : DXKSVE
```

The result I seek after matching or filtering  is like

**filtered  Array Object 1**

```
number : 1730
Place  : NY
Color  : white
Zone   : TVQJPN
Group  : 2



number : 2199
Place  : PA
Color  : blue
Zone   : AAYYSN
Group  : 4



number : 2746
Place  : NJ
Color  : red
Zone   : DXKSVE
Group  : 17
```

What I ended up doing was some "Feature Engineering" and combining the 4 fields that are unique as a combo into one string and added that as a property to each of the Array Objects. `Combo = Place + Color + Zone + Group`

Example

```
number : 1730
Place  : NY
Color  : white
Zone   : TVQJPN
Group  : 2
Combo  : NYwhiteTVQJPN2
```

Assume `$wholearray` is the bigger more fuller array and `$partialobject` is the one smaller one we need to filter by.

The Following is my **CURRENT CODE**

```bsh
    $wholearray.ForEach({
        $thisline = $_ ;
        $combo = $thisline.Place + $thisline.Color + $thisline.Zone + $thisline.Group;
        $wholearray.Where({$_ -eq $thisline}) | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Combo -NotePropertyValue $combo
    }

    $partialobject.ForEach({
        $thisline = $_ ;
        $combo = $thisline.Place + $thisline.Color + $thisline.Zone + $thisline.Group;
        $partialobject.Where({$_ -eq $thisline}) | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Combo -NotePropertyValue $combo
    }

    $filtereddata = $wholearray.Where({$_.Combo -in $($partialobject.Combo)})
```

It works with an average processing time of 0.08secs per instance in the loop
But its still Slow. It will take 5 mins just for a couple of thousand rows/instances. When I have to do this with 20k or more it would be a disaster. All The while it could be done in 15 secs with even more rows in Excel using vlookup. And POSH or CLI should be faster than Excel.

**How can I make this more efficient?**

**How can I make this faster?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `Compare-Object` could accomplish your task.

As `Compare-Object` isn't known for speed you've got at least an alternative to measure  time.

```
$Filtered = Compare-Object -Ref $WholeArray -Diff $PartialArray `
                           -Property Place,Color,Zone,Group `
                           -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru
```

To remove the inserted property `SideIndicator` you might do:

```
$Data = $Filtered | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator
```

Comment: Thanks this worked EXTREMELY well and was fast too. I tested it without the Passthru and it didnt work. Do you mind explaining why that is?

Comment: Sorry missd your comment, Without `-PassThru` you get only the named properties in the response, here with `-IncludeEqual` you get all properties from the `-ReferenceObject` plus the `-SideIndicator`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using this code and a lookup Hashtable will speed things up for you:

Add the `Combo` property to the `$wholearray` objects:

```
$wholearray | ForEach-Object {
    $combo = '{0}{1}{2}{3}' -f $_.Place, $_.Color, $_.Zone, $_.Group
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Combo -Value $combo
}
```

For the objects in the partial array, you create a Hashtable object:

```
$lookup = @{}

$partialarray | ForEach-Object {
    $combo = '{0}{1}{2}{3}' -f $_.Place, $_.Color, $_.Zone, $_.Group
    $lookup[$combo] = $true   # the key is the important thing here, the value doesn't matter
}
```

Then get your filtered data using:

```
$filtereddata = $wholearray | Where-Object { $lookup.ContainsKey($_.Combo)}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much. This is amazingly faster than my method (10 seconds compared to 20 mins). And it keeps the feature engineering front too for when I need to do so in the future. However, for when I don't need the feature engineering I will be using the `Compare-Object` with a `-passthru` (4 secs).